# How to show shortcode in Wordpress menu?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I tried add my language select shortcode as custom link, as menu item to a menu, but WP puts a `http://` before the shortcode, and nothing appears in the menu, why? What is wrong? I can not remove `http://, WP always puts it back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the wrong URL.
Here's how you can do it.

1. In the WP dashboard, Go to Appearance > menu.
2. Create a new menu or edit the existing menu.
3. Click on the custom Link.
4. In the URL field enter the language switcher shortcode. hear is an example of it. EX. if your shortcode is **[language_switcher]** and  it is on a page called **Language Switcher**. then would be **https://yourwebsite.com/language-switcher/**
5. In the Text field enter your menu text.
6. Click on **Add to menu** and save your menu.

**Note:** Update the **yourwebsite.com** with your domain name.